# is there a way to set permissions like drwxr-xr-x 2?

Tags: command-line, permissions, privileges

I  can't get my head around priviledges and permissions in Linux. I want to set permissions of `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority` to `drwxr-xr-x 2 755` which its permissions set to

```
stat -c %a localauthority
700
```

by udev and it gave me much trouble, because current user can not reach some of operations in session, for example, it can not mount a partition with user permissions.

So I wanted to set it to 755 thinking that it would grant the current user rw permissions.

After I issued

```
chown 755 -R /etc/polkit-1/localauthority
```

and I checked permissions I noticed that it only applied in `root` user.

```
stat -c %a localauthority


1351907 drwx------ 7 755 root 4.0K Nov 19 17:04 localauthority
```

I want it to have

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 755
```

It would be easier to set permissions with letters instead of numbers.

Is there a way to set it like

```
set-permission drwxr-xr-x  localauthority
```

?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?  Most of the /etc/ stuff should be left well enough alone.

Comment: `sudo chmod 755  /etc/polkit-1/localauthority`

Comment: Is there an easier way to set permissions instead of `sudo chown 755 ./directory` ?

Comment: Here is one of several tutoroals on linux permissions - http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php . I agree with @ThomasW. , you should not be needing to change ownership and permissions of system files, especially as a new user. Doing so is a great way to break your system. You need root (sudo) access to modify files outside of your home directory. This is a security feature. See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: @bodhi.zazen
Thank you for the links. As A.B stated in his answer  I foolishly used wrong command. But I still wonder if there is a command to set it with letters.

Comment: Of course see man chmod. chmod a+x the first letter who to change u -= user = owner , g = group , o = other , then + to add or - to remove , then rwx . chmod u+rwx chmod o-rwx , chmod u+rx , etc See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Oh, yes. I remember I read it somewhere. It's exactly what I asked for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chown` changes file owner and group and not the permission bits. Use

```
sudo chmod 755  /etc/polkit-1/localauthority
```

or with

```
sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx  /etc/polkit-1/localauthority
```

But the is **absolutely no reason to change** the permission. In other words, changing the permissions is a security risk.

With your wrong command

```
chown 755 -R /etc/polkit-1/localauthority
```

you have recursively changed the owner to `755`. Correct this with

```
sudo chown root -R /etc/polkit-1/localauthority
```

Comment: You are right A.B. I foolishly used wrong command.  Apart from my foolisness, Can not we set it with letters as I stated in my question?

Comment: Also note @A.B. it is considered a security risk to mess with files inside /etc/ especially the polkit stuff

Comment: @ThomasW. You're right, warning added. Thank you.

Comment: @kenn alternative way added

Comment: I agree with @ThomasW. , just because someone asks how to do something does not mean we should simply answer the question without warnings ;)